# Angular 5 next button on dynamic component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, contentful

Im not sure if this is even possible but.. I have a page that brings in a list of items from an external api, so there are 5 elements on the page now each element is a link to its own page which is generated dynmically through querystrings so for example `[routerLink]="['page', item.fields.id]"` now what I want to do is have a next button on the generated page that goes to the next items generated page

my set up is as follows...

**contenful.service.ts**

*So this sets up my api calls*

```
 // Get all the program items
 getProgramItems(query?: object): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
    return this.cdaClient.getEntries(Object.assign({
      content_type: CONFIG.contentTypeIds.programItems
    }, query))
    .then(res => res.items);
 }
 // Get only the program items with specified week
 getWeekItems(week: number): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
    return this.getProgramItems({'fields.week': week});
 }

 // Get program with certain id
  getAsset(id: string): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
    return this.getProgramItems({'sys.id': id});
  }
```

**week-1.component.ts**

*This is were im calling the data and then displaying the list of items*

```
export class Week1Component implements OnInit {
  private programItems: Entry<any>[] = [];
  private week1Items: Entry<any>[] = [];

  constructor(
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.contentfulService.getWeekItems(1)
      .then((week1Items) => {
        // set week1Items one and order them by sequenceOrder
        this.week1Items = _.orderBy(week1Items, ['fields.sequenceOrder'], ['asc']);
        })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(this.week1Items);
      });
  }
```

**week-1.component.html**

*This is where i display the list items and have the `routerLink` where the page is dynamically created*

```
 <div class="program_card" *ngFor='let item of week1Items'>
      <span class="program_card_part-number">Part {{item.fields.sequenceOrder}}</span>
      <div class="program_card_title">
        <span class="program_card_title_main">{{item.fields.assetTypeHeading}}</span>
        <span class="program_card_title_sub">{{item.fields.title}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="program_card_inner">
        <div [routerLink]="['asset', item.sys.id]" class="program_card_inner_icon_{{item.fields.assetType}}"></div>
        <img src="{{item.fields.overviewImage.fields.file.url}}">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="item.fields.comment" class="program_card_comment">
          <div class="program_card_comment_radius-fix"></div>
          <img src="../../../assets/Images/image.jpg">
          <p>{{item.fields.comment}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**asset-page.component.ts**

```
export class AssetPageComponent implements OnInit {
  asset: Entry<any>[];

  constructor(
     private contentfulService: ContentfulService,
     private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.contentfulService.getAsset(params.get('id')))
    .subscribe(asset => {
      this.asset = asset;
      console.log(this.asset);
    });
  }

}
```

so what I want to do is on the dynamically created asset page is have a next button which goes to the next dynamically created asset page from the list on the week-1 page... like I said I'm not even sure if something like this is possible but any help would be appreciated! and let me know if you need any more information

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to do is have the response from getProgramItems be stored in some sort of state management service. Possibly even just within the service that fetches the data. This way, once it's retrieved, any component that injects the service can access the data. Then, maybe even separate the dynamic link out into a directive that you can just pass one of the program items into.

Do some searches for state management services in Angular.

If you find yourself having to share data across components a lot, I would recommend looking into a tool like NGRXStore. It'll help you manage API data that needs to be shared across parts of your application in a very clean and efficient way.